# Disable CHKDSK without being able to bootup

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bsod, chkdsk

The system I am working on started to randomly reboot, thinking it was a harddrive error (we've had two machines fail due to this already), I rebooted the computer to run chkdsk.

Now the problem is that waiting the 1.5 hours for CHKDSK to complete, causes it to reboot without finishing, and hitting any key to skip CHKDSK blue screens with PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA.

Booting into safemode hangs on AGP40.sys, but booting the computer normally before I tried to do CHKDSK worked until it decided it was time to reboot itself.

Anyways, my goal is to simple disable the automatic CHKDSK on bootup. While speculations as to the root cause of this issue is welcome, the only thing I'm currently concerned with is getting the machine up temporarily.

And with CHKDSK running at bootup causing a crash, that is difficult.

I have learned how to do a LoadHive, however I have no idea which registry I file I need to load from C:\Windows\System32\Config\ nor where in that file I can load it from.

I currently have the harddrive in another machine, so I can do a loadhive, or do some config file modifications if necessary.

Side Note: Hardware is fine, moved harddrive to another machine and still fails to boot  for the same reasons (while that machine boots just fine with it's own harddrive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is set in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute

Sounds like you have bad hardware on that box, motherboard or powersupply is likely.

Excerpt from http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~mgoetsch/cali/Windows%20Configuration/Windows%20Configuration%20Html/ModifyingDefaultBootupRunofCHKDSK_F.htm

Normally it is set to

```
autocheck autochk *
```

To prevent CHKDSK /F from running for NTFS partition D: the entry becomes:

```
autocheck autochk * 
autocheck autochk /k:D
```

To force CHKDSK /F for drive D: when the Dirty Bit was not set the entry becomes

```
autocheck autochk * 
autocheck autochk /m:D
```

Comment: Thanks, trying this using LoadHive, it's not a hardware problem though, added a note to the bottom of my question.